# Any FPGA ability to analyze on-board?

Tags: verilog

I am working with the Digilent Basys3 board, and have a project where the simulation's timing diagram doesn't reflect what actually happens on the board. This discrepancy makes it difficult to troubleshoot, because I can't get an accurate timing diagram on the hardware.

From the Basys3 reference manual, it says that "the system edition includes an on-chip logic analyzer" -- does this mean that I can get a timing analysis from the board, without using a digital analyzer? Also, do digital analyzers show *all* the signals from a board, or only those output via PMODs? Because my project uses all of the available PMOD ports, so if it requires free PMOD ports, it would be useless even if I had one.

Comment: *"the simulation's timing diagram doesn't reflect what actually happens on the board."* The first thing to do then is to check your timing constraints. (You can have dozens of errors and it is a waste of time trying to find them using an ILA)

Comment: I'm a student and just started learning digital logic this quarter. Not an excuse; just trying to indicate my experience level (beginner). My professor gave our class the constraints file to use, so I am using what was given to me. Where are the timing constraints -- in the .xdc constraints file? How do I check them, and how do I know what they should be?

Comment: Run a timing check after you ran place & route. (Run Implementation) There is a button for that in Vivado under "Implementation". It will tell you if your design fails timing and what the failing path(s) are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're probably implying that you can use the Vivado ILA (formerly Chipscope) to debug the internals of your FPGA design.  Take a peek on YouTube for Xilinx Vivado ILA and you should be able to find some videos that give a good overview of this process.